# Запуск стороннего процесса средствами JAVA

Tags: java

Запустить сторонний процесс из Java несложно, достаточно воспользоваться `ProccessBuilder`-ом, но в вот в чем вопрос возник: возможно ли запустить процесс из Java, который не завершится после закрытия породившей его программы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, возможно (а почему вообще он должен завершиться?).

```
ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder();
p.command("notepad.exe");
p.start();
```

Откроется стандартный `notepad.exe`, который не закроется при завершении запустившей его программы.